# Why is the return value of personality(2) in a Go program sometimes incorrect?

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

I've written a Go program that is supposed to disable ASLR by passing `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` as the *persona* argument to the [`personality(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) system call. It uses the `unix.Syscall` function from the `golang.org/x/sys/unix` package to do so.

After disabling ASLR, the program runs an infinite loop, in which it gets the current persona without changing it by calling `personality(2)` with a *persona* argument of `0xffffffff` (as described in the man page) and reports whether the `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` bit is set.

When the program is run, the persona seems to go back and forth between `0x00040000` (the expected value with the `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` bit set) and `0x00000000` (no bits set, which is unexpected).

Sample output of the program:

```
good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
... [Repeats many times]
bad - ASLR is not disabled (0x00000000)
bad - ASLR is not disabled (0x00000000)
bad - ASLR is not disabled (0x00000000)
... [Repeats many times]
good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
... [Repeats many times]
... [And so on]
```

Here is the source code for the program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

// https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/personality.h
const addrNoRandomize = 0x0040000

func main() {
    disableAslr()

    for {
        curPersona := getCurrentPersona()
        if curPersona&addrNoRandomize != 0 {
            fmt.Printf("good - ASLR is disabled (0x%08x)\n", curPersona)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("bad - ASLR is not disabled (0x%08x)\n", curPersona)
        }
    }
}

func disableAslr() {
    persona := getCurrentPersona()

    if persona&addrNoRandomize == 0 {
        ret, _, errno := unix.Syscall(syscall.SYS_PERSONALITY, uintptr(persona|addrNoRandomize), 0, 0)
        if int(ret) == -1 {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("disable aslr: %v", errno))
        }
    }
}

func getCurrentPersona() int {
    persona, _, errno := unix.RawSyscall(syscall.SYS_PERSONALITY, uintptr(0xffffffff), 0, 0)
    if int(persona) == -1 {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("get current persona: %v", errno))
    }
    return int(persona)
}
```

This behavior is unexpected because:

1. The man page says nothing to suggest that the personality should go back and forth like this
2. An equivalent C program consistently shows the personality being set to `0x00040000` - it never reverts back to 0
3. Watching `/proc/<PID>/personality` for the PID of the Go program *consistently* shows `00040000`. It never goes back to 0. This suggests to me that `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` is indeed set properly, but the program is reporting it incorrectly
4. Using `strace` on the Go program shows that `personality(2)` is only called with an argument of `0x00040000` (to disable ASLR) or `0xffffffff` (to get the current persona without changing it). There are no other calls changing it back to 0

Comment: Just some guesses ... (1) The syscall uses `unsigned int` but `getCurrentPersona` returns `int` (2) In the loop, you call `getCurrentPersona` _twice_: `curPersona := getCurrentPersona() if getCurrentPersona()&addrNoRandomize != 0` Would calling it just once be better: `curPersona := getCurrentPersona() if curPersona & addrNoRandomize != 0`? (3) If you ever get `bad`, do a few more iterations and then abort. The _return_ value of the syscall from `strace` may be interesting.

Comment: Fixed #2, thanks for pointing that out, @CraigEstey. The program behavior is still the same, however.  For #1, the man page states that the syscall returns `int`, which is why `getCurrentPersona` returns that type. I will investigate #3.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C? I removed that.

Comment: I think the `personality()` syscall is thread and not process scoped. I've added an answer that shows how to use the [libcap/psx](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/psx) to work around this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any detail about this in the man page for [`personality(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html), but this seems to
be the same issue as [why `setuid()` and friends](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435) were not supported by Go, under Linux, for a very long time.

Go's idea of threading is not easy to reason about. You can force a single OS thread to follow the execution of a single sequence of code with `runtime.LockOSThread()`, but getting all OS threads in a Go program to share many kernel maintained attributes is sometimes difficult and non-obvious.

There is a package, [`kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/psx`](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/psx), that mirrors system calls over all OS threads. In cases like this it addresses the problem you are seeing.

Rewriting your application (`prog.go`) to use the `psx` package, controlled with a command line flag, makes it work as you expect:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "syscall"

    "kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/psx"
)

var wPSX = flag.Bool("psx", false, "disable ASLR with PSX thread mirroring")

// https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/personality.h
const addrNoRandomize = 0x0040000

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    disableAslr()

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        runtime.LockOSThread()
        curPersona := getCurrentPersona()
        tid := syscall.Gettid()
        runtime.UnlockOSThread()
        if curPersona&addrNoRandomize != 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%d: good - ASLR is disabled (0x%08x)\n", tid, curPersona)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%d: bad - ASLR is not disabled (0x%08x)\n", tid, curPersona)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        go func() {
            // Cause one OS thread to exit.
            runtime.LockOSThread()
        }()
        // Allow this code to run on a different thread.
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}

func disableAslr() {
    persona := getCurrentPersona()
    if persona&addrNoRandomize != 0 {
        return
    }
    var ret uintptr
    var errno syscall.Errno
    if *wPSX {
        ret, _, errno = psx.Syscall3(syscall.SYS_PERSONALITY, uintptr(persona|addrNoRandomize), 0, 0)
    } else {
        ret, _, errno = syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_PERSONALITY, uintptr(persona|addrNoRandomize), 0, 0)
    }
    if int(ret) == -1 {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("disable aslr: %v", errno))
    }
}

func getCurrentPersona() int {
    persona, _, errno := syscall.RawSyscall(syscall.SYS_PERSONALITY, uintptr(0xffffffff), 0, 0)
    if int(persona) == -1 {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("get current persona: %v", errno))
    }
    return int(persona)
}
```

I've dropped the `unix` package as it doesn't help with anything in this case, and you are already including the `syscall` package.

```
$ go mod init prog
$ go mod tidy
$ go build
$ ./prog --psx=false
24381: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24381: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24381: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24387: bad - ASLR is not disabled (0x00000000)
$ ./prog --psx=true
24368: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24369: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24370: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24371: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24372: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24374: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
24373: good - ASLR is disabled (0x00040000)
...
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate to rain on the parade, but, it just occurred to me ...

1. Disabling ASLR [if enabled] for the *current* program will have little effect, because it happens *too late* in the loading process. The *kernel* [and, possibly, the ELF interpreter] has *already* applied ASLR.
2. Disabling ASLR will only have an effect on a program that we do `execvp` on.
3. To disable ASLR for the current program requires that we disable it, and, then, do *exec* of the current program and its args.

Note that a C program doesn't have to do this for *threads* because they haven't been created yet.

For a `go` program, we may have to do what Tinkerer did in his answer (e.g. using `psx`, etc., to catch all threads).

Since I'm not too familiar with `go`, here is a C program (and we need the equivalent in `go`):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/personality.h>

int
disableAslr(void)
{
    // get current state
    unsigned int pers = personality(0xFFFFFFFF);

    // decide if we need to disable (and exec)
    int doexec = ((pers & ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE) == 0);

    // disable ASLR (for child of execvp)
    if (doexec)
        personality(pers | ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE);

    return doexec;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    // disable ASLR and self exec [if necessary]
    if (disableAslr())
        execvp(argv[0],argv);

    // real stuff ...

    return 0;
}
```